# Ms Access Field Checking for nulls, but it is checking previous records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

**My problem is:** When calling onclose it goes to the first record of the form,
and looks at those values. Does the onClose of MS Access forms requery? If so, what is another work around for me?

**Background**
I am building a program in MS Access. A form needs to be checked to determine if there are any nulls before it can be accepted as a finished report. I am checking Text boxes and Combo boxes.

I add my fields into two collections:
AllTB 
AllCB

I am calling Field Checker Form.onClose

```
Private Sub fieldchecker()
Dim tb As Textbox
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0
For Each tb In AllTB
    If IsNull(tb.Value) Or tb.Value = "" Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next tb

Dim cb As ComboBox
For Each cb In AllCB
    If IsNull(cb) Or cb.Value = "" Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next cb 
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Close()
Call tssfieldchecker
If IsOpen("frm_Data") Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Nav"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the _Unload_ event. At Close, data are gone.

Comment: Normally you would use the forms 'BeforeUpdate' event to validate entries. http://www.databasedev.co.uk/confirm-record-update.html

Comment: I disable the form X close and use a custom button to save and/or close. Code to validate data is behind button. I have never used form BeforeUpdate.